# Convert HTML SharePoint form data into a PDF file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, sharepoint

I want to convert a HTML Page into PDF which has a form which allows user to enter data. So once the "*Save as PDF*" button is pressed the code should be able to read the data from the Input Boxes and create a PDF..

Since its a internal site created using **SharePoint**, the link or file cannot be shared/transeffered to another site.

Example:

```
    <div id="mainContentWide">
  <h2>WorkPlace Services</h2>
    <h3 class="curveBoxWide">Description</h3>
    <div class="curveBoxWide">
  <p></p></div>
  <table id="mytab1">
        <thead>
            <tr class="thead item">
                <th>One</th>
                <th>Two</th>
                <th>Three</th>
                <th>Annual Price ($)</th>
                <th>One time Extended Cost ($)</th>
                <th>Annual Extended Cost ($)</th>
                <th>Sub-Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>aaa</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">136</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>bbb</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">368</td>
                <td>85</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>ccc</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">270</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>ddd</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">180</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
                <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>eee</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">0</td>
                <td>1600</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>fff</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">0</td>
                <td>700</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>ggg</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">915</td>
                <td>220</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>hhh</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">0</td>
                <td>550</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>iii</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">0</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item category">
                <td colspan="7"><p>jjj</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>kkk</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">125</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>lll</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">160</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>mmm</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">220</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>nnn</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">550</td>
                <td>110</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>ooo</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">1050</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>ppp</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">4210</td>
                <td>850</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>qqq</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">125</td>
                <td>210</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>rrr</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">160</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>sss</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">685</td>
                <td>154</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>ttt</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">5210</td>
                <td>1470</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>uuu</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">4740</td>
                <td>940</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>vvv</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">800</td>
                <td>380</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>xxx</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">3750</td>
                <td>850</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>yyy</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">32000</td>
                <td>7100</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item category">
                <td colspan="7"><p>zzz</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="title"><p>abc</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">2850</td>
                <td>570</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>       
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>def</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">1125</td>
                <td>225</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item odd">
                <td class="title"><p>ghi</p></td>
                <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
                <td class="price">3750</td>
                <td>750</td>
                <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td class="title"><p>Total:</p></td>
                <td class="grandTotal" colspan="6"><input id="total" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/castelinokelvin/tqefoqw7/

**Tried**: jspdf, it didnt work.

Comment: Why could you not use jsPdf? It is the simplest way to create a pdf from javascript as far as I know.

Comment: jsPDF doesnt read values from the input boxes.. It comes as undefined..

Comment: jsPDF shouldn't have to read the values? Look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9xjxt30/). You would read the value with jQuery, or standard DOM selectors.

Comment: That examples is ok, with one text box and convert that input text to PDF..
I have a table with 20 rows and 5 coulmns, with Input boxes in every cell.. And there are 5-6 pages with different dimensions of tables.. 
So it should be saved as PDF in the same structure..

Comment: It could work ok in that example as well. You would just have to create some for loops. Look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/s9xjxt30/1/). You would necessarily have to modify it to suit your needs, but you have full control over what is written where, so you just have to write the proper code for it.

Comment: From your example, look into something like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/tqefoqw7/1/) which captures and converts html into pdf. You will likely need to write some special object handlers and adjust the options a little, but it should provide you with what you want.

Comment: If you check the saved PDF it doesnt have the values from the input boxes.

Comment: Yes, but that is just 3 lines of code. Getting the values from the input boxes can be done as shown earlier, manually. I don't think there is an easier way, unfortunately. You might be able to modify jsPdf to include the values, which might be easier tho.